# bluetooth headset can connect, but not visible in pulse audio

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have a plantronics bluetooth headset, and until yesterday I could use it without any problem. However, today it suddenly stopped working (maybe related to the last software update I did). I can still connect/disconnect my headset, but it doesn't show up in pulse audio anymore. I read through various posts that describes kind of the same problem, but none of the suggested solutions worked. I get following error in the syslog:

```
Oct 13 16:49:57 desktop bluetoothd[1040]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Oct 13 16:49:57 desktop bluetoothd[1040]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Oct 13 16:49:57 desktop bluetoothd[1040]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Oct 13 16:50:09 desktop kernel: [   17.340943] input: 48:C1:AC:08:FE:8F as /devices/virtual/input/input14
Oct 13 16:50:09 desktop bluetoothd[1040]: /org/bluez/1040/hci0/dev_48_C1_AC_08_FE_8F/fd0: fd(36) ready
Oct 13 16:50:09 desktop rtkit-daemon[1894]: Successfully made thread 2213 of process 1892 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct 13 16:50:09 desktop rtkit-daemon[1894]: Supervising 5 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct 13 16:50:10 desktop bluetoothd[1040]: Badly formated or unrecognized command: AT+XEVENT=USER-AGENT,COM.PLANTRONICS,PLT_VOYAGERPRO,0109,27.90,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Oct 13 16:50:10 desktop bluetoothd[1040]: Audio connection got disconnected
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks, 
Kim

Comment: Did you try if removing the device in Bluetooth settings and then re-pairing solves the issue?

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work. There is a very similar bug ([link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/972063)), so I added my information to that one. The error is different though (Badly formated ... AT+XEVENT), but let's see if anything turns up.

Comment: This is a promising find indeed. However I cannot confirm it here (Jabra/Philips SHB7102).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this helped:

```
sudo apt-get-install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

and then reboot, restart bluetoothd, etc, etc, and then your headset is visible.